# Android - use generated C files with JNI

Tags: android, c, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to create an application using C files.

In fact, the C files were generated from matlab (~20 files, with `.c` and `.h`), and I didn't modify those files.

To use those files with JNI, I create an other C file which is using JNI : `native-lib.c`.

So the C files generated by matlab are used through `native-lib.c` (I used a tuto found on the web to write this file).

I have this architecture for the c files :

```
src/
-- jni/
---- native-lib.c
---- include/
-------- All the c files generated from matlab
```

And this is `native-lib.c` (that I simplify here):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "include/function1.h"


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
My_project_function1(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, Function1_Args args) {

    int x = function1(args);
    return x;

}

etc...
```

To build the C library I use this file : `CMakeList.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native-lib SHARED src/jni/native-lib.c)

include_directories(src/jni/include)

find_library(log-lib log)

target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib})
```

But this file `CMakeList.txt` doesn't work ! All the files in the folder `include/` are not included in the project (only `native-lib.c` is recognize).

So I want to include the files of the `include/` folder WITHOUT modify them (without adding `JNIEXPORT`, `JNICALL`, etc...).

I almost never use C, and I know nothing about the C generation. So I don't know how to do, and I don't understand most of the answers found on the web :(

Is someone understand why `CMakeList.txt` doesn't work? Do you have a solution to solve my problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem :

It is very simple in fact :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

file(GLOB sources_c
    "src/jni/include/*.h"
    "src/jni/include/*.c"
    "src/jni/native-lib.c"
)

add_library(native-lib SHARED ${sources_c})

find_library(log-lib log)

target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib})
```

I just put all the C files in the variable `sources_c` with `file(GLOB sources_c ...)`.

And, in `CMakeList.txt`, it seems that there is any distinction between pure C files and JNI-C files (C files with, `JNIEXPORT`, ect ...).

I hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CMake, however, You probably want to either add the src/jni/include folder as a second library source and static link to native-lib, or add the contents of src/jni/include directly to the arguments of add_library(native-lib SHARED ...).  Please note that include_directories are for #include paths and not for src locations.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the `include_directories` is not for the sources path. So I think I have to add all the sources through `add_library` (even if the files are not modified to be use with JNI).